# std::find is having issues in xutility C++

Tags: c++, find, c++-cli, std

In my program I have a function that looks like this

```
bool InstalledProgram::IsProgInList(String^ ProgramName, list<InstalledProgram> ListCheck) {
if (find(ListCheck.begin(), ListCheck.end(), ProgramName) != ListCheck.end()) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}

When I go to debug the whole thing I get

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xutility(3045) : see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::_Find<_InIt,_Ty>(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &,std::false_type)' being compiled
    with
      [
          _InIt=std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<InstalledProgram>>>,  
          _Ty=System::String ^
     ]
```

It doesnt tell me anything about my actual code file but this is the only place I am using find, so it has to be here.  I have spent a while trying to get around this with now luck.  Can anyone see a problem? I know that `ProgramName` is supposed to be `String^ const &_Val` but I am not sure I understand what that means and how its different.

Answer (score 0):

The container `ListCheck` contains object of type `InstalledProgram`, but you're searching an element of type `String^` (`c++-cli`)

You probably need to define a custom unary predicate and use `std::find_if`